# Get name of a property which raizes SerializationException

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I serialize large complex object using `BinaryFormatter` and serialization of some property leads to `SerializationException`. How can I get information about what property causes error?

Of course, I can get name of the type which can't be serialized, but I can't find the property containing an instance of the type.

Exception message looks like:

```
Type "MyType" from assembly "MyAssembly" is not marked as serializable.
```

Instance of this type should not exist in the object serialized and I can't find the property which contains it.

To serialize I use this simple code(where data is an instance of my complex type):

```
...
var str = new MemoryStream();
var bf= new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(stream, data);
...
```

Comment: AFAIK the exception will tell this. Post the exception you get. Also what is the cause of the exception you're talking about?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I've updated the post. the problem is that i cannot find any information about the property from SerializationException raised

Comment: Do you have a class MyType in your code? If yes the does it have [Serializable] tag on it?,

Comment: There are infinite possibilities that an object can hold a reference to another somehow. Maybe property is typed as `Object`, that it could hold anything in it. You need some kind of recursive algorithm to find what is the runtime type of `MyType` inside the object which you're trying to serialize. You'll do it with reflection.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez yes, this class is written by me and it has no and should not have this attribute.

Comment: Then you should manually write the file. I guess you need this tag to write object automatically. I faced similar kind of issues when I was trying to write an XML file for the object.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, if not find any other solution so I will use reflection, but it looks like implementation of a part of serializator class(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the object has been found using reflection

```
private bool TrySerialize(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return true;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        bf.Serialize(stream, obj);
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private string FindObject(Stack<object> self, Type typeToFind, string path)
{
    var _self = self.Peek();
    if (self.Where(x => x.Equals(_self)).Count() > 1) return null;
    foreach (var prop in _self.GetType().GetMembers().Where(x => !x.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(y => y is XmlIgnoreAttribute)))
    {
        switch (prop.MemberType)
        {
            case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property:
                {
                    var line = string.Format("{0}::{1}", path, prop.Name);
                    var _prop = prop as PropertyInfo;

                    if (_prop.GetIndexParameters().Count() > 0) break;

                    if (typeToFind.IsAssignableFrom(_prop.PropertyType))
                        return line;


                    if (_prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || _prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || _prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                        continue;

                    var subInst = _prop.GetValue(_self, new object[0]);
                    if (subInst == null)
                        continue;

                    if (!TrySerialize(subInst))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0,"",string.Format("Cannot serialize {0}\n", line));
                    }

                    self.Push(subInst);
                    var result = FindObject(self, typeToFind, line);
                    self.Pop();
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
                break;
            case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field:
                {
                    var line = string.Format("{0}::*{1}", path, prop.Name);
                    var _prop = prop as FieldInfo;

                    if (typeToFind.IsAssignableFrom(_prop.FieldType))
                        return line;

                    if (_prop.FieldType.IsPrimitive || _prop.FieldType == typeof(DateTime) || _prop.FieldType == typeof(string))
                        continue;

                    var subInst = _prop.GetValue(_self);
                    if (subInst == null)
                        continue;

                    if (!TrySerialize(subInst))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "", string.Format("Cannot serialize field {0}\n", line));
                    }

                    self.Push(subInst);
                    var result = FindObject(self, typeToFind, line);
                    self.Pop();
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
                break;

            case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Event:
                {
                    var line = string.Format("{0}::!{1}", path, prop.Name);
                    var _prop = prop as EventInfo;


                    if (typeToFind.IsAssignableFrom(_prop.EventHandlerType))
                        return line;

                    var field =  _self.GetType().GetField(_prop.Name,
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.GetField);


                    if (field!=null && !field.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(x=>x is NonSerializedAttribute) 
                        && !TrySerialize(field.GetValue(_self)))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "", string.Format("Cannot serialize event {0}\n", line));
                    }


                }
                break;

            case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Custom:
                {

                }
                break;
            default: break;
        }


    }
    if (_self is IEnumerable)
    {
        var list = (_self as IEnumerable).Cast<object>();
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            index++;
            self.Push(item);
            var result = FindObject(self, typeToFind, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", path, index));
            self.Pop();
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

To use call in such way:

```
string result = FindObject(new Stack<object>(new object[] { instanceToSearchIn }), typeof(MyType), "[myself]");
```

and as result I've got:

```
[myself]::RootSection::Children[0]::Children[0]::Item
```

**UPDATE:**

This code now also tests members for serialization

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Serializable tag on your class which you are trying to serialize.

Here is an example. I have a class name Point2D which has some properties and serialize tags.

```
[Serializable]
public class Point2D
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public double X { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the serialization code.

```
var point2D = new Point2D { X = 2, Y = 3 };
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var bf= new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(stream, point2D);
```

Comment: As described in answer, I must not use this class

Comment: Question is something different as I read it. It is not how to fix the problem rather how to find which field or property causing this problem.

Comment: @FLCL I am writing xml files using this. I will update you if I am able to find answer for your case,